# A book about the Roman Empire surviving to modern times

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book where the Roman Empire never fell, but survived and prospered into modern times to develop space travel by the end of the book. Not sure how long ago, at least after the nineties.The cover had a rocket launching I think.I had it in paperback

Comment: When and where did you read this? Was it a paperback? Hardback? eBook? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: Not sure how long ago, at least after the nineties.The cover had a rocket launching I think.I had it in paperback

Comment: If you edit the question, you can add those details;. :)

Comment: Wikipedia lists eight novels in that vein - worth checking into those: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction_set_in_the_Roman_Empire#Alternate_universe_fiction

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it.

The book is [Roma Eterna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma_Eterna) by Robert Silverberg.

[image: Book cover]

> The novel is presented as a series of vignettes over a period of about 1500 years, from 1282 ab urbe condita (AD 529) to 2723 AUC (AD 1970). Most of the story-chapters involve Roman politics, either the competition between the Western and Eastern Empires to dominate the other or the violent creation of the Second Roman Republic in about 2603 AUC (AD 1850). Others describe the first Roman circumnavigation of the world and unsuccessful attempts to conquer Nova Roma (North America).